# Bootstrap DateTimePicker localisation is en-us even though I am specifying en-gb

Tags: javascript

I'm using the DateTimePicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent in a project at the moment. I have two date fields (start and end date) that I would like to display the date in a format for the current users locale.

In Chrome, I am using a plugin that allows me to specify the Accept-Language header which I'm setting as `en-GB`. ASP.NET Core picks this up fine, but if I use the following function in my Javascript then it outputs `en-US`, which I find very strange, why would it be different and could this be the cause of my problems?

```
function getLang()
        {
         if (navigator.languages != undefined) 
         return navigator.languages[0]; 
         else 
         return navigator.language;
        }
```

The problem is the DateTimePicker, when you select a date is rendering the date format in the field in US format of `mm-dd-yyyy` rather than the UK format of `dd-mm-yyyy`. Here's how I'm registering the date picker;

```
$('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'L',
                useCurrent: true,
                locale: 'en-gb',
                icons: {
                    next: "fas fa-angle-right",
                    previous: "fas fa-angle-left"
                }
            });
```

In the datepicker form field, I have the date as `10/07/2019` (10th July 2019), when I focus on the datepicker field, the calendar opens up on October rather than July.

Why is the datetimepicker plugin ignoring my request to have the date in `en-gb` format rather than `en-us`?

I've put a quick example on Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rcq9zLe7/3/ . When I click in the date field, the calendar that appears shows October instead of July.

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale says `You must include moment-with-locales.js or a local js file`. Did you do that too?

Comment: Yes I have included moment.js

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this. I was only including `moment.js` in my project, to work with locales you have to include `moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js` instead.